# Mongodb multitenant in .NET core project

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core, multi-tenant

I am using .NET Core and MongoDB. Currently it's a single database project. Now I want to implement multi-tenancy in my project. That is separate database for different users. When the user login the site, and based on that user details, want to select connection string.

https://web.archive.org/web/20140812091703/

http://support.mongohq.com/use-cases/multi-tenant.html

https://gunnarpeipman.com/aspnet/tenant-providers/

But  the problem is I have no idea to how to implemet this in my existing code?

My existing code is

```
public MetaphorsContext(IMongoClient client,
                        IMongoDatabase database)
{
  _client = client;
  _database = database;
}

public IMongoCollection<Location> Locations
{
  get ???
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your approach involves different databases in the same cluster, then you do not need different connection strings but merely a dictionary that maps each tenant ID to its respective `MongoDatabase`:

```
public IDictionary<string, IMongoDatabase> Databases = ...

string tenantID = ...

Databases.TryGetValue(tenantID, out var database);

// use database to get collections
```

If the different databases are kept in different clusters, then you can have a dictionary that maps each tenant ID to its respective `MongoClient`.

```
public IDictionary<string, IMongoClient> Clients = ...

string tenantID = ...

Clients.TryGetValue(tenantID, out var client);

// use client's databases and their collections
```

Comment: can you please give some more details?

Comment: What details do you further require?

Comment: I have a main db called "TenantManagement", then when user login , then check the   tenant name in this db. So we get the connection string, and use this connection string for that particular user. Is it possible to do this way? Every user have different db.

Comment: At some point you will have to cache your users's clients/databases (in case you are having different database for users), and that's where the dictionary will help. How that dictionary is loaded/initialized is up to your use-case requirements. If, for example, there aren't many users, you can load all the connection strings during startup and initialize the mongoDB clients so that subsequent requests use those pre-initialized clients for access.